# Top rows of answer missing after running a summary of a GEE model

Tags: r

I am using Rstudio to run a generalised estimating equation with the following formula:

```
    new <- gee(deaths~ subtypes,
       data = hi, family = "binomial", id = iso,
       corstr = "exchangeable", scale.fix = TRUE, scale.value = 1)
```

Then , I wanted to get the robust standardised erros by running:

```
    summary(new)
```

but the answer in the console starts somewhere in the middle like this

```
    [71,] 0.01557088 0.01557088
    [72,] 0.01557088 0.01557088
    [73,] 0.01557088 0.01557088
    [74,] 0.01557088 0.01557088
    [ reached getOption("max.print") -- omitted 60 rows ]
```

I want it to look something like this(obtained through R not Rstudio).

```
    GEE:  GENERALIZED LINEAR MODELS FOR DEPENDENT DATA
    gee S-function, version 4.13 modified 98/01/27 (1998) 

    Model:
    Link:                      Logit 
    Variance to Mean Relation: Binomial 
    Correlation Structure:     Exchangeable 

    Call:
    gee(formula = deaths ~ subtypes, id = iso, data = hi, family =    "binomial", 
corstr = "exchangeable", scale.fix = TRUE, scale.value = 1)

    Summary of Residuals:
    Min         1Q     Median         3Q        Max 
    -0.5882720 -0.5824096  0.4175904  0.4175904  0.4909421 


    Coefficients:
                    Estimate Naive S.E.     Naive z Robust S.E.    Robust z
     (Intercept)  0.33267295  0.1214047  2.74019759   0.1604175  2.07379434
     subtypes2   -0.29643730  0.3437622 -0.86233233   0.4620348 -0.64159083
     subtypes3    0.02415334  0.2680558  0.09010566   0.2650652  0.09112226

     Estimated Scale Parameter:  1
     Number of Iterations:  3
```

How can I achieve this in Rstudio without the top parts of the answer being omitted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like `summary.gee` has a flag that might hide the display of the working correlation, if the code was implemented.

```
> gee:::summary.gee
function (object, correlation = TRUE, ...)
{
...
    if (correlation) {
    }
...
}
```

If this ever becomes implemented, `summary(new, correlation=FALSE)` might help.

Until then, you can manipulate the `summary.gee` object.

```
> g <- gee(breaks ~ tension, id=wool, data=warpbreaks, corstr="exchangeable")
> s <- summary(g)
> s
...
Working Correlation
            [,1]       [,2]       [,3]       [,4]       [,5]       [,6]
 [1,] 1.00000000 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404
 [2,] 0.02518404 1.00000000 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404
 [3,] 0.02518404 0.02518404 1.00000000 0.02518404 0.02518404 0.02518404
...
> s$working.correlation <- NULL
> s
...
Working Correlation
NULL
```

(You could set the `working.correlation` to NULL in the actual `gee` object, but doing it in the summary preserves the original output.)

Comment: @flexy if this solved your problem consider accepting it by pressing on the tick on the left

Comment: @Josh how do i get the p-values from the coefficient estimates?

Comment: @flexy I don't see an automated way to do it, but something like `1-pnorm(abs(summary(g)$coef[,3]))` (for naive) or `1-pnorm(abs(summary(g)$coef[,5]))` (for robust) should work.